# Can't figure out how to populate an input based on Autocomplete suggestion select

Tags: php, jquery, forms, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a form with a section for adding inventory items. The are 3 inputs per row. "Item Description, Item Number and Quantity". They are standard dynamic inputs so I can add and remove rows as necessary.

The first input "Item Description" uses jquery autocomplete. This works great. What I would like to do is have the "Item Number" input auto fill based on the autocomplete selection. I have this partially working. It will fill in the "Item Number" fine for the first row, but as I add new rows the auto fill changes every rows "Item Number". The regex is also working perfect.

Here's my code.

```
$("#add").click(function(){
        $('input[name="item_description[]"]').autocomplete({
            source: 'fetchData.php',
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('input[name="item_number[]"]').val(ui.item.id);
            },
        }); 
    });
    

    $('body').on('keyup change', 'input[name="item_description[]"]', function() {
        
        $('input[name="item_description[]"]').autocomplete({
            source: 'fetchData.php',
            
        });
        
        let matches = false;
        var regx = /(one|five|eight)/gmi;
        
        $('input[name="item_description[]"]').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val().match(regx)){  
            matches = true;
            }
        });

            if (matches){  
                $("#numdiv").show();
                $("#lblnumdiv").show();
            }
            
            else {
                $("#numdiv").hide();
                $("#lblnumdiv").hide();;
            }
    });
```

and the php

```
<?php 
// Database configuration 
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'yyyyy';
$dbpass = 'yyyyy';
$db = 'yyyyy';
 
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db); 
 
if ($db->connect_error) { 
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error); 
} 
 
$searchTerm = $_GET['term']; 
 
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_inventory WHERE inv_name LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY inv_name ASC"); 
 
$invData = array(); 
if($query->num_rows > 0){ 
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
        $data['id'] = $row['inv_id']; 
        $data['value'] = $row['inv_name']; 
        array_push($invData, $data); 
    } 
} 
 
echo json_encode($invData); 
?>
```

I've tried adding the select: function to the auto complete like so. This works for the first row. Adding new rows changes the Item Number for every previous row.

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('input[name="item_number[]"]').val(ui.item.id);
```

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This does not seem like a good way to initialize the Autocomplete. I understand you are adding dynamic content and then need to use Autocomplete on that. Doing it under a keystroke is not a good idea in my mind. I would do this in the Click event so that when a key is pressed, autocomplete is already initialized.

Comment: Per Twisty's suggestion I moved the autocomplete init to the click function. Problem is the same.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone else, this solved my problem. Whether it's right or not, I don't know. But it works.

```
    $('input[name="item_description[]"]').autocomplete({
            source: 'fetchData.php',
            select: function (event, ui){
            event.preventDefault();
                $(this).closest("tr").find('input[name="item_number[]"]').val(ui.item.id);
                $(this).closest("tr").find('input[name="item_description[]"]').val(ui.item.value);
                    },
                });
         },
    });
```